# d3 library installed with npm doesn't load json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, d3.js

I just installed d3 using npm. In `package.json` it shows on dependencies `"d3": "^4.11.0" version,`.

I tried to load a simple json file with the next code:

```
const d3 = require('d3')

d3.json('jsonfile.json', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  data.keys.map((t) => {
    console.log(t)
  })
})
```

But I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
```

The json file is actually ok. I verified using this tool: https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator.

However, when I removed this line `const d3 = require('d3')` and inserted the script directly in the HTML file:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/d3.min.js'></script>
```

...using 3.5.5 version, the json file was loaded.

Is there something new in `d3` version `^4.11.0` in order to load local files?

Comment: Did you try the same solution with the v4 script? `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Hi. It works ok also with that line. I think the problem is after `d3` is installed using `npm`, specially with new versions. I have been reading files using `require('d3')`, but is until now that I have that `SyntaxError:`.

Comment: Are you running this in a browser or as a nodejs app? I cannot reproduce this problem in a browser when using webpack to create a bundle. If you run it in a browser then how does the browser solve the `require` function? Browser JavaScript does not have require unless you use requirejs or bundle your code with something like webpack.

Comment: Hi, @HMR. I am using nodejs app. I am using `browserify` and `gulp` to do some tasks, such to create a `bundle.js` file.

Comment: I had same issue installing version d3 6.3.1 and could not get data to load from local url from php but worked perfectly with `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your code as a node app you have to load json with the full url:

```
const d3 = require('d3');
//use full url to where the json file is
d3.json('http://localhost:8080/jsonfile.json', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  data.keys.map((t) => {
    console.log(t)
  })
});
```

If you want to run the code as a node app and load the file from disk you could load the file like so:

```
fs = require('fs');
const readFile = (file,encoding) => 
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>
      fs.readFile(
        file
        ,encoding
        ,(err,data) => {
          if(err !== null){
            reject(err);return;
          }
          resolve(data);
        }
      )
    )
;

readFile("./static/jsonfile.json",'utf8')
.then(
  data =>
    data.toString()
).then(
  text =>
    console.log("Got file content:\n",text)
  ,err =>
    console.error("Failed to load file:",err)
);
```

If your code runs in a browser but you want to use npm as dependency management then you can use requirejs (old way) or webpack (better but a bit more complicated to learn and set up). If you are using your code in a browser I wonder how you do not get an error on `const d3 = require('d3');`.

Comment: Thanks, @HMR. I was not using full url to where the json file is. I suppose I need to change the url when project is in production, right? So,in order to not change url, the second option using `fs` would be the best choice, right? Thanks again.

Comment: @RamiroTormenta It depends, if the data is on disk then use file. Here is an example of how to use d3 in node: https://gist.github.com/palanik/ba5e15dbbc7ea0574ae0d38252563b0d because node doesn't have DOM you have to use `node-jsdom`, when d3 has created an svg you can use the `outerHTML` to get it's content.

Comment: Excellent tip, thank you. So, if I want to even select just an id using d3, node-jsdom ` var document = jsdom.jsdom()` is a must, right? Thanks for this doc.

Comment: @RamiroTormenta It seems that d3 needs a node to work with: `d3.select(jsdom.jsdom().body).append('svg').attr ... .append("g") ...` Since node doesn't have a build in window and window.document you'll need a library that'll provide this and jsdom seems to do the trick. I haven't used d3 in this way yet but most samples I see use jsdom.